# Difference between the two style of calling a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor

Hi fellow developers,

I was asked to implement the following
let num = new Mathematics(5).add(5).sub(8).add(8).getVal();
console.log(num) // 10

Below is my implementation:

```
function Mathematics(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.add = (val)=>{
        this.value += val;
    }
    ;
    this.sub = (val)=>{
        this.value -= val;
    }
    this.getVal = ()=>{
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now when I run this it like below it will thrown an error.

```
let num = new Mathematics(5).add(5).sub(8).add(8).getVal();
```

But if I call it like below the code works perfectly

```
const num = new Mathematics(5);
num.add(5);
num.sub(8);
num.add(8);
console.log(num,getVal()); // 10
```

Upon searching online, I found that what was missing was that I needed to return this in the add() and sub() methods.

Can somebody explain why I have to return this and, moreover, what is the difference between the two ways by which I am calling methods?

```
function Mathematics(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.add = (val)=>{
        this.value += val;
        return this;
    }
    ;
    this.sub = (val)=>{
        this.value -= val;
        return this;
    }
    this.getVal = ()=>{
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is called function chaining.

When you do `.add(5).sub(8)`, you're calling `.sub` on the result of the function call to `.add(5)`. If you don't return `this`, and instead return nothing, then you'd be calling `.sub` on `undefined`.

You can also implement chaining like this:

```js
class Mathematics {
  constructor(val) { this.value = val; }

  add(val) {
    this.value += val;
    return this;
  }
  sub(val) {
    this.value -= val;
    return this;
  }
  get val() {
    return this.value;
  }
}


let {val} = new Mathematics(5).add(5).sub(8).add(8);

console.log(val);
```